# Парсинг текста

Tags: c++, синтаксический-анализ

Например, у меня в переменной записан текст. Вот пример

```
HolidaysPage: false, 
'PhotoImagineHost': '', 
'VideoPerlHost': '', 
'ActiveFirstName': '&nbsp;', 
'ActiveLastName': '&nbsp;', 
'my_xhtml_path': '/ru/css/my_xhtml.css?70', 
'my_mf_path': 'mf_css_xhtml.css?98', 
'Validate': '', 
'mna': '123456', 
'mnb': '', 
'Owner': '', 
'ActiveID': '', 
'ActiveEmail': '', 
'IsFemale':'', 
'MyMailDir': '', 
'MyMailEmail': '', 
'MyMailName': '', 
'MainPage':0, 'megaGifts': [],
```

Как мне вытащить оттуда 123456? При том, что значение вместо 123456 изначально не известно.

***с++/cli***

**заранее спс =)**

Answer (score 1):

Ищете в строке подстроку `'mna'` (например, с помощью функции [`string::find`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/)), пропускаете двоеточие, пробел и кавычку и считываете символы до следующей кавычки.

Comment: Приглядевшись к тексту вопроса, обнаружил: 

    HolidaysPage: false,
    ....
    'IsFemale':'',

из чего следует, что обнаружив 'mna', видимо надо сразу искать кавычку, а на двоеточие и пробелы (сколько их возможно ?) можно не смотреть.

Также очевидно, что представление значений в этом списке имя-значение зависит от типа. Видимо mna и IsFemale строкового типа (и их значения  в кавычках), HolidaysPage логическое, MainPage это число, а megaGifts - вектор (тут пустой)(тип элементов наверное надо определять по формату записи значений).

**Вообще-то, желательно знать описание формата данных**.

Comment: ну не то что я хотел мне нужно например указываю с чего начинается и на чем заканчивается записать данные между ними в переменную

Comment: @rif009 Вам придется самому это реализовать или использовать стороннюю библиотеку. Или мы Вас неправильно понимаем, объясните подробнее.

Answer (score 0):

Это похоже ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
getstrval (char *text, char *name, int *iname, int *ival)
{
  *iname = *ival = -1;
  if (!name || !*name)
    return NULL;

  int l = strlen(name);
  char *pat = malloc(l+3),
    *beg, *res = NULL;

  sprintf(pat,"'%s'",name);
  if (!(beg = strstr(text,pat)))
    goto END;
  *iname = beg-text+1;  // индекс начала имени

  // ищем начало Value
  int i;
  for (i = *iname+l+1; text[i]; i++) { 
    // Здесь халтура - несколько ':' тоже OK
    switch (text[i]) {
    case '\'':
      *ival = ++i;     // индекс начала Value
      goto VEND;
    case ':':
    case ' ':
    case '\t':
      break;
    default: // недопустимый символ
      goto END;
    }
  }
  goto END; // не нашли начала Value

 VEND:;
  char *end = strchr(text+i,'\'');  // тоже халтура '\ не учитываем
  if (!end)
    goto END;
  l = end-(text+i);
  res = malloc(l+1);
  strncpy(res,text+i,l);
  res[l] = 0;

 END:
  free (pat);
  return res;
}

main ()
{
  char *text = "'abc': '1234', 'zz' : '24567', 'rrrr''66', 'rr' : '5";
  int n,v;

  char *nm = "ab";
  char *p = getstrval(text,nm,&n,&v);
  printf ("%s: [%s] %d %d\n", nm,p,n,v);

  nm = "abc";
  p = getstrval(text,nm,&n,&v);
  printf ("%s: [%s] %d %d\n", nm,p,n,v);
  nm = "zz";
  p = getstrval(text,nm,&n,&v);
  printf ("%s: [%s] %d %d\n", nm,p,n,v);
  nm = "rrrr";
  p = getstrval(text,nm,&n,&v);
  printf ("%s: [%s] %d %d\n", nm,p,n,v);
  nm = "rr";
  p = getstrval(text,nm,&n,&v);
  printf ("%s: [%s] %d %d\n", nm,p,n,v);
}
```

Результат:

```
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ gcc f.c
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $ ./a
ab: [(null)] -1 -1
abc: [1234] 1 8
zz: [24567] 16 23
rrrr: [66] 32 38
rr: [(null)] 44 51
c:/Users/avp/src/cc/hashcode $
```

Comment: public string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd, int startPos){
    int iPos, iEnd, lenStart = strStart.Length;
    string strResult = "";

    iPos = strSource.IndexOf(strStart, startPos);
    iEnd = strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, iPos + lenStart);

    if(iPos != -1 & iEnd != -1){
        strResult = strSource.Substring(iPos + lenStart, iEnd - (iPos + lenStart));
    }
    return strResult;
}

public string GetBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd){
    return GetBetween(strSource, strStart, strEnd, 0);
}

Comment: вот функция на с++\ cli объясните как ей пользоваться а то у мну компилятор ругается 
юзать так: Pars(text, "с чего парсить", "по что парсить", 0)

Comment: объясняю что я хочу я отправляю гет запрос странице получаю ответ ввиде хтмл кода и тд и мне нужно оттуды спарсить нужную мне инфу

Comment: Пример (на C) Вам показали, принцип объяснили, далее сами.